# Use of GET method in Python for ServiceNow Tables

Tags: python, api, servicenow

I’m trying to import Task table from ServiceNow using api. 
There is a python script which does the import from Incident table.
I’m just seeing people dealing with the Incident table. But, I am looking for the Task table.

I am sorry if I failed to explain this situation better.
Thanks!

Comment: In the example scripts that you are using, replace the **incident** table with **task** table.